# How should I use storage class specifiers like ref, in, out, etc. in function arguments in D?

Tags: reference, arguments, d, storage-class-specifier

There are comparatively many storage class specifiers for functions arguments in D, which are:

- *none*
- `in` (which is equivalent to `const scope`)
- `out`
- `ref`
- `scope`
- `lazy`
- `const`
- `immutable`
- `shared`
- `inout`

What's the rational behind them? Their names already put forth the obvious use. However, there are some open questions:

1. Should I use `ref` combined with `in` for `struct` type function arguments by default?
2. Does `out` imply `ref` implicitely?
3. When should I use *none*?
4. Does `ref` on classes and/or interfaces make sense? (Class types are references by default.)
5. How about `ref` on array slices?
6. Should I use `const` for built-in arithmetic types, whenever possible?

More generally put: When and why should I use which storage class specifier for function argument types in case of built-in types, arrays, structs, classes and interfaces?
(In order to isolate the scope of the question a little bit, please don't discuss `shared`, since it has its own isolated meaning.)

Comment: `ref in` should work, but doesn't. I think I've filed the bug, but it doesn't seem to be a priority, sadly.

Comment: @Mehrdad I think they already fixed it - it works for me(on dmd)

Comment: The error message "incompatible parameter storage classes" jumps at me as well. I'm using dmd 2.059. What are you using?

Comment: @RalphTandetzky 2.060 is the most recent release. He's probably using that.

Comment: @IdanArye: Weird, [the bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=8121) doesn't look like it was marked as resolved...

Comment: @Mehrdad I just had a look onto the changelog of version 2.060. Bug 8105 "in ref" is mentioned there as resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I wouldn't use either by default. `ref` parameters only take lvalues, and it implies that you're going to be altering the argument that's being passed in. If you want to avoid copying, then use `const ref` or `auto ref`. But `const ref` *still* requires an lvalue, so unless you want to duplicate your functions, it's frequently more annoying than it's worth. And while `auto ref` will avoid copying lvalues (it basically makes it so that there's a version of the function which takes an lvalues by `ref` and one which takes rvalues without `ref`), it only works with templates, limiting its usefulness. And using `const` can have far-reaching consequences due to the fact that D's `const` is transitive and the fact that it's undefined behavior to cast away `const` from a variable and modify it. So, while it's often useful, using it by default is likely to get you into trouble.

   Using `in` gives you `scope` in addition to `const`, which I'd generally advise against. `scope` on function parameters is supposed to make it so that no reference to that data can escape the function, but the checks for it aren't properly implemented yet, so you can actually use it in a lot more situations than are supposed to be legal. There are some cases where `scope` is invaluable (e.g. with delegates, since it makes it so that the compiler doesn't have to allocate a closure for it), but for other types, it can be annoying (e.g. if you pass an array be `scope`, then you couldn't return a slice to that array from the function). And any structs with any arrays or reference types would be affected. And while you won't get many complaints about incorrectly using `scope` right now, if you've been using it all over the place, you're bound to get a lot of errors once it's fixed. Also, its utterly pointless for value types, since they have no references to escape. So, using `const` and `in` on a value type (including structs which are value types) are effectively identical.
2. `out` is the same as `ref` except that it resets the parameter to its `init` value so that you always get the same value passed in regardless of what the previous state of the variable being passed in was.
3. Almost always as far as function arguments go. You use `const` or `scope` or whatnot when you have a specific need it, but I wouldn't advise using any of them by default.
4. Of course it does. `ref` is separate from the concept of class references. It's a reference to the variable being passed in. If I do

   ```
   void func(ref MyClass obj)
   {
       obj = new MyClass(7);
   }

   auto var = new MyClass(5);
   func(var);
   ```

   then var will refer the newly constructed `new MyClass(7)` after the call to `func` rather than the `new MyClass(5)`. You're passing the reference by `ref`. It's just like how taking the address of a reference (like `var`) gives you a pointer to a reference and *not* a pointer to a class object.

   ```
   MyClass* p = &var; //points to var, _not_ to the object that var refers to.
   ```
5. Same deal as with classes. `ref` makes the parameter refer to the variable passed in. e.g.

   ```
   void func(ref int[] arr)
   {
       arr ~= 5;
   }

   auto var = [1, 2, 3];
   func(var);
   assert(var == [1, 2, 3, 5]);
   ```

   If `func` didn't take its argument by `ref`, then `var` would have been sliced, and appending to `arr` would not have affected `var`. But since the parameter was `ref`, anything done to `arr` is done to `var`.
6. That's totally up to you. Making it `const` makes it so that you can't mutate it, which means that you're protected from accidentally mutating it if you don't intend to ever mutate it. It *might* also enable some optimizations, but if you never write to the variable, and it's a built-in arithmetic type, then the compiler knows that it's never altered and the optimizer should be able to do those optimizations anyway (though whether it does or not depends on the compiler's implementation).

   `immutable` and `const` are effectively identical for the built-in arithmetic types in almost all cases, so personally, I'd just use `immutable` if I want to guarantee that such a variable doesn't change. In general, using `immutable` instead of `const` if you can gives you better optimizations and better guarantees, since it allows the variable to be implicitly shared across threads (if applicable) and it *always* guarantees that the variable can't be mutated (whereas for reference types, `const` just means only that that reference can't mutate the object, not that it can't be mutated).

   Certainly, if you mark your variables `const` and `immutable` as much as possible, then it does help the compiler with optimizations at least some of the time, and it makes it easier to catch bugs where you mutated something when you didn't mean to. It also can make your code easier to understand, since you know that the variable is not going to be mutated. So, using them liberally can be valuable. But again, using `const` or `immutable` can be overly restrictive depending on the type (though that isn't a problem with the built-in integral types), so just automatically marking everything as `const` or `immutable` can cause problems.

Comment: Hey thanks. Learned a lot. Every answer was very enlightening. :)

Comment: @Jonathan M Davis "In general, using immutable instead of const if you can gives you better optimizations and better guarantees": That's true for variables, but for function parameters it's often the opposite: Using const if immutable is not absolutely necessary is more convenient, as it also allows mutable arguments.

Comment: @jpf `const` and `immutable` can still be big for optimizations with function parameters. e.g., if a function's parameters are `immutable` and the function is `pure`, then that function is "strongly pure" and multiple calls to it within an expression can be elided. But just like transivity can make `const` or `immutable` undesirable in some situations, using `immutable` can be undesirable because it forces you to pass `immutable` arguments (or arguments which implicitly convert to `immutable`). But that's a usability thing, not an optimization thing. What's best depends on the function.